# SocketException: Permission denied: connect in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am recording my client web application. Till 3-4 steps I am able to record but after clicking on one option. I am getting page of "Connect to network" while clicking on the connect button, it will open new tab were I am getting bellow error.

How to overcome this and proceed with recording?

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at `enter code here`org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:318)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:695)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:454)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:244)
```

Comment: Manually application is working fine on web browser. And I am getting above error message on http://www.gstatic.com/generate_204. I think its a google CDN?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in JMeter "bin" folder)

   ```
   java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
   ```

   and restarting JMeter to pick the property up
2. Try upgrading to [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and [JMeter 3.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3) (or whatever latest version is available at [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)
3. Try the latest [JMeter Nightl](http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html)y build

Going forward please include at least essential parts of *jmeter.log* file into your question so we could see JMeter version, Java version, etc.